# Java Как узнать передали ли методу ВСЕ аргументы или какой-то НЕ передали?

Tags: java, методы, аргументы

Метод должен принять два массива. Не знаю как выполнить пункт 1((((((

1. Если одного из массивов передано не было - надо вернуть ЛОЖЬ
2. Если оба массива пустые - вернуть ИСТИНУ
3. Если длины у массивов разные - вернуть ЛОЖЬ

Мне  аргументы машина передает. Я сама не знаю что она передает, но могу попросить у машины сказать мне длину массива. Машина передала мне два массива. Я спросила у машины длину массива первого, она ответила 0, а про длину другого массива молчит.. не пойму

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class AreSame {
    
    public static boolean comp(int[] a, int[] b) {

   //checking arrays length     
        if(a.length != b.length){
                return false;        
        }
        
        if((a.length == 0) && (b.length == 0)){
                return true;        
        }
        //ЗДЕСЬ ПЫТАЮСЬ ПОЙМАТЬ ЧТО ОДИН ИЗ МАССИВОВ ПЕРЕДАН НЕ БЫЛ В ДАННЫЙ МЕТОД... НО НЕ СРАБАТЫВАЕТ
        if((a[0] < 0) || (a[0] >  0) || (a[0] =  0) || (b[0] < 0) || (b[0] >  0) || (b[0] =  0)){
                int z = 0;        
        } else return false;
        
        

  
        }
    //sorting array a
  Arrays.sort(a);
  
  //sorting array b
  Arrays.sort(b);

  }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте на `null`

Comment: @Artem Berezovski а как это? дайте код пожалуйста

Comment: if (a == null || b == null) return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Что понимать под "Если одного из массивов передано не было"?

   В Java вы не можете просто так "не передать какой-то аргумент" если его запрашивает метод, а значит ваше условие слегка непонятно.

   Если же речь идет о проверке того что переданное значение не `null`, так тут все просто. Проверяете на `null`.

   ```
   if (array1 == null || array2 == null) return false;
   ```
2. "Если оба массива пустые - вернуть ИСТИНУ":

   ```
   if(array1.length == 0 && array2.length == 0) return true;
   ```
3. "Если длины у массивов разные - вернуть ЛОЖЬ":

   ```
   if(array1.length != array2.length) return false;
   ```

Comment: а если один массив имеет длину ноль, а другой массив не имеет длины? Тот массив что не имеет длины - он null? Мне просто аргументы машина передает. Я сама не знаю что она передает, но могу попросить у машины сказать мне длину массива. Машина передала мне два массива. Я спросила у машины длину массива первого, она ответила 0, а про длину другого массива молчит... вот и не понятно какая разница между пустым массивом не имеющим элементов И так называемым null.

Comment: Если массив не имеет длины он null. Другого состояния в Java нет.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю о какой машине идёт речь и что откуда и как вам возвращается. Но в Java объект либо есть и он что-то в себе хранит либо его нет и он null. Причем второе актуально только для ссылочных типов данных. Так как любой от примитив имеет значение по умолчанию. А вот что подразумевает ваша "машина" я не могу вам сказать. Что это за машина, на чем она написана, главное как написана и т.д.